# How to reverse each slice with specific size in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice, reverse

I have a one-dimensional array whose elements are either 1 or 0. Looking at blocks of 8 elements each, I want to reverse the order of elements within a block but leave the order of blocks intact. For instance, let's say we have an array A consisting of two blocks:

`A = [0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0]`

After this operation, it needs to be like this:

```
A = [1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0]
```

I have currently this solution:

```
A.reshape(-1,8)[:,::-1].reshape(-1)
```

Since I am doing this operation on many and large one dimensional arrays, I want to do it as efficient as possible.

Is there a more efficient solution (like using only one `reshape` method)?

Comment: I think that aproach is already pretty fast. In my system, replacing `.reshape(-1)` with `.flatten()` gives a bit extra performance

Comment: What's the datatype of input array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get a minimal speedup by replacing the second reshape with a [ravel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
In [1]: A = np.asarray([1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0])

In [2]: %timeit -r 1000 -n 1000 A.reshape(-1,8)[:,::-1].reshape(-1)
2.12 µs ± 427 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1000 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit -r 1000 -n 1000 A.reshape(-1,8)[:,::-1].ravel()
1.47 µs ± 362 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1000 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

I also assumed that using [flip](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) would further improve the efficiency, but (oddly) this seems to not be true:

```
In [4]: %timeit -r 1000 -n 1000 np.flip(A.reshape(-1, 8), 1).ravel()
2.39 µs ± 531 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1000 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**EDIT:**

For large arrays, the efficiency seems to be the other way around:

```
In [1]: A = np.random.randint(2, size=2**20)

In [2]: %timeit -r 100 -n 100 A.reshape(-1,8)[:,::-1].reshape(-1)
1.01 ms ± 13.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 100 runs, 100 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit -r 100 -n 100 A.reshape(-1,8)[:,::-1].ravel()
1.11 ms ± 10.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 100 runs, 100 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit -r 100 -n 100 np.flip(A.reshape(-1, 8), 1).ravel()
1.11 ms ± 10.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 100 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Since OP mentioned `large one dimensional arrays`, maybe test out with those?

Comment: `.ravel()` increased the performance just a little bit, but it is better than nothing. Thanks. :)